# Conditional Formatting: Check if cell is min value compared to all cells above it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, excel-2013

In Excel, starting in C2 I have a column of numbers.

I would like a conditional formatting rule applied to every number in that column that checks to see if it is smaller than all the numbers above it. If it is, it should be green.

For example:

```
185.1
186.7
185.4
184.9
185.0
183.6
```

184.9 and 183.6 should both be green.

After selecting all the values in the column, I created the following conditional formatting rule:

```
Format values where this formula is true:   ="<MIN($C$2:C2)"
```

...and then the format is set to have green text. It Applies to =$C$2:$C$150

But it doesn't work :(

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `C3`, try `=C3=MIN(C$2:C3)` Applies to `=$C$3:$C$150`. (Though personally I'd accept C1 and C2 being green and for Applies to use =$C:$C, with =C1=MIN(C$1:C1).)

Comment: +1 hadnt seen this when I answered

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain why this doesn't belong on SO?

Comment: Close it, hold it, or do whatever you want, I got an answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Select `C3:C150`  (not `C2`)
- Add this rule, `=C3<MIN($C$2:C2)`